# Ignite cache data is lost when docker container is restarted

Tags: ignite

I want to enable persistence in ignite so that when ignite docker container is restarted or replaced with new version cache data is not lost.

I am using ignite 2.6.0. Here is the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
   <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
      <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                  <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />
               </bean>
            </property>           
            <property name="storagePath" value="/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/data/persistence" />           
            <property name="walPath" value="/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/data/wal" />
            <property name="walArchivePath" value="/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/data/wal/archive" />
         </bean>
      </property>          
      <property name="discoverySpi">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">            
               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                  <property name="addresses">
                     <list>
                        <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47502</value>
                     </list>
                  </property>
               </bean>
            </property>
         </bean>
      </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

I ran following command to deploy ignite docker container

```
sudo docker run -d -e "CONFIG_URI=" -e "OPTION_LIBS=ignite-core,ignite-spring,ignite-indexing,ignite-rest-http" -v /var/ignitedata:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/data -p 9005:8080 --name=apacheignite apacheignite/ignite:2.6.0
```

I did not pass any value to CONFIG_URI is because i replace the default-config.xml file in the docker container.

I created a new cache using ignite rest api

```
http://localhost:9005/ignite?cmd=getorcreate&cacheName=myCache
```

Added sample values to cache

```
http://localhost:9005/ignite?cmd=put&key=10&val=2018-01-01&cacheName=myCache&keyType=int&valueType=date
```

I can retrieve the cache value

```
http://172.30.5.28:9005/ignite?cmd=get&key=10&cacheName=myCache&keyType=int&valueType=date
```

Now if i restart the docker container and try retrieving value, it does not return value

```
http://localhost:9005/ignite?cmd=get&key=10&cacheName=myCache&keyType=int&valueType=date
```

Has anyone seen this issue?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: @stephen-darlington Thank you for your reply. from the docker container i ran command ./control.sh --activate . then added the data to cache, verified that i am able to retrieve the data. Then i restarted docker container, ran ./control.sh --activate again, tried fetching the value it did not work.

Comment: Autoactivation should be called when all nodes from baseline topology will be started if persistence is on. I think that possibly you didn't set IGNITE_HOME variable in your container and working directory with binary_metadata was created in tmp folder. After docker restart, this folder was cleared. Try to set the working directory manual - https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setWorkDirectory-java.lang.String-. Try to clear storagePath, walPath, walArchivePath. Set the working directory and retest your case.  Is it help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate the cluster after you started it? When you use persistence, you need to tell Ignite how many nodes it should expect to see (called the "baseline").

You do that by running the `control.sh` script:

```
./control.sh --activate
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that docker container still has same storage mounted, and also set consistentId to same value in configuration.

If you do that, cluster will auto-activate once all nodes have joined. You only have to activate it manually once.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andrei Aleksandrov for pointing me to correct direction. I added working directory path and that helped in resolving the issue.
Posting the updated default-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
   <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
      <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
      <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                  <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />
               </bean>
            </property>



         </bean>
      </property>
      <property name="workDirectory" value="/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/data" />
      <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide a list of initial nodes. -->
      <property name="discoverySpi">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
               <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
               <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                  <property name="addresses">
                     <list>
                        <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                        <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47502</value>
                     </list>
                  </property>
               </bean>
            </property>
         </bean>
      </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```